# Can anyon explain me what the following command does?

Tags: linux, cygwin

I have a python script which contains the following command in `subprocess.call()`

```
find spath -type f -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p `dirname ${0//old/new}`' {} ; -exec bash -c 'cp -rf $0 ${0//old/new}' {} ;
```

This is how I run my script:

```
python script.py dir/old new
```

spath is the first argument that I pass to the script

when I run the above command It creates a copy of old in dir as new. But I don't understand how it is happening.

Comment: break it into parts and test them.

Comment: Could you please tell me what exactly $0 referes to here ?